# How can Sebastian use "I am a butler and a devil" so casually?

Tags: japanese-language, black-butler

To my ears, the Japanese means:

> I am an akuma (demon), and a shitsuji (butler).

I guess it must have a pun meaning, too. On one occasion, a bad guy cried out "a-a-akuma?", but that's the exception: everybody seems cool after hearing it. How can Sebastian say this so casually?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yeah, it's a pun. When read

> 悪魔で執事ですから
>   akuma de shitsuji desu kara

It means

> I'm a devil and a butler, you see.

Whereas, when read as the identical-sounding

> 飽くまで執事ですから
>   aku made shitsuji desu kara

It means

> I'm a butler through and through, you see.

---

This pun (*aku made* vs. *akuma de*) is a relatively common one in Japanese. For an example of a second-order pun of this variety, see the omake at the end of episode 26 of Yowamushi Pedal:

[image: I'm a sheep through and through]

The fellow on the right was transformed from being a sheep to a (human) butler, and so instead of saying *aku made **shitsuji** desu kara* "I'm a butler through and through", he says *aku made **hitsuji** desu kara* "I'm a sheep through and through" (butler = *shitsuji*, sheep = *hitsuji*; cf. [What do the sheep dolls represent in Mayo Chiki?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14433/)).

---

Additional note: the `aku` in the two examples are homophones that mean different things. The `aku` in my first example is `悪`, which means "evil". The `aku` in my second example is `飽く`, which is a verb meaning "to grow tired of" (you see its more common synonym `飽きる` = `akiru` more often).

The compound construction `aku made` (`飽くまで`) means "until I grow tired of ~" when viewed as two different words, and means "completely" or "thoroughly" when viewed as a fixed idiomatic compound (this latter usage is standard; analyzing it as a verb+`まで` is not).

The official English translation by Funimation aptly captures the meaning and magnitude of this pun by translating it as "You see, I'm merely one hell of a butler." This reflects both his demonic nature as well as his skills as a servant using a common English expression that has more or less the same meaning.

Comment: Whats the literal meaning of "aku made"? I believe "aku" still means "evil", but its not a red flag

Comment: @aitchnyu They're homophones that mean different things. The `aku` in my first example is `悪`, which means "evil". The `aku` in my second example is `飽く`, which is a verb meaning "to grow tired of". The compound construction `aku made` (`飽くまで`) means "until I grow tired of ~" when viewed as two different words, and means "completely" or "thoroughly" when viewed as a fixed idiomatic compound.

Comment: Now I notice "akumade" in all anime I watch, even when the subtitles are not faithful. Awesome answer!