# What do the sheep dolls represent in Mayo Chiki?

Tags: mayo-chiki

[image: Sheep!]

Are these sheep dolls mascots, or do they represent something in the series? From the look of it, the blood (?) drooling from their mouths is like Sakamachi Kinjirou's nose bleed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a mascot for the series. Subaru is a butler, and in Japanese, "butler" ([shitsuji](http://jisho.org/search/shitsuji)) and "sheep" ([hitsuji](http://jisho.org/search/hitsuji)) sound the same, making it a play on words. The reason it is bleeding is itself a pun because a sheep bleats.

Comment: can you provide any links or cite it to back your answer

Comment: I'm going to have to call BS on that "bleeding" / "bleating" pun unless you can provide a source. That pun is pretty much exclusive to English--furthermore, it's exclusive to dialects of English that pronounce the *t* in "bleating" like a *d*, i.e. mainly dialects from the midwestern United States. It would be *very* obscure to Japanese viewers, and the creators would have needed extensive knowledge of English to come up with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the original Japanese language of *Mayo Chiki!*, **these sheep plushies are known as "Silent Lamb" (沈黙ヒツジ).**

[image]

<sup>The "Silent Lamb" card from *Precious Memories* Trading Card Game</sup>

Not much information known regarding this thing other than it is Subaru's favorite sheep character.

Judging from its name, fans theorized that it refers to [*The Silence of the Lambs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silence_of_the_Lambs_(novel)) which features a *cannibalistic* character and a scene of *the protagonist's childhood memory related to lambs*.