# What about Sebastian's footprints?

Tags: black-butler

In the [Phantomhive Manor Murders Arc](http://kuroshitsuji.wikia.com/wiki/Phantomhive_Manor_Murders_Arc), in the Manga, when the murders were happening, the characters who were investigating specifically mentioned that there were no footprints of anyone from outside who might have come from storm or might've been wet because of rains near the crime scenes.

But later

> when Sebastian was explaing that he was behind everything and that he switched corpse places from outside windows. Also he was shown wet a number of times. But no footprints were found? There were no footprints of the wet Sebastian? How?

Was mentioning the "no traces of footprint" thing a mistake or was it ignored while sebastian was explaining what had actually happened?

Comment: Remember what he says every time? "I am the butler of the Phantomhive family. It goes without saying that I can manage something like this." That's how he can walk without leaving footprints.

Comment: He is merely, one *hell* of a butler.

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade actually using the Japanese version of the quote would deliver it better. See http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5122/how-can-sebastian-use-i-am-a-butler-and-a-devil-so-casually

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many things Sebastian can do that we can't explain without shining some light on one fact.

He is "***Simply, one hell of a butler***"

He is merely an interesting creature with many talents.